# how to fix 'undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status'

Tags: c, gcc, opencl

When I am trying to compile the host code using `make` command. It gave me this error:

```
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/host] Error 1
`
```

Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(VERBOSE),1)
ECHO :=
else
ECHO := @
endif

# Where is the Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM) software?
ifeq ($(wildcard $(INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT)),)
$(error Set INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT to the root directory of the Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM) software installation)
endif
ifeq ($(wildcard $(INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT)/host/include/CL/opencl.h),)
$(error Set INTELFPGAOCLSDKROOT to the root directory of the Intel(R) FPGA SDK for OpenCL(TM) software installation.)
endif

# OpenCL compile and link flags.
AOCL_COMPILE_CONFIG := $(shell aocl compile-config )
AOCL_LINK_CONFIG := $(shell aocl link-config )

# Compilation flags
ifeq ($(DEBUG),1)
CXXFLAGS += -g
else
CXXFLAGS += -O2
endif

# Compiler
CXX := g++

# Target
TARGET := host
TARGET_DIR := bin

# Directories
INC_DIRS := ../common/inc
LIB_DIRS :=


# Files
INCS := $(wildcard )
SRCS := $(wildcard host/src/*.cpp ../common/src/AOCLUtils/*.cpp)
LIBS := rt pthread

# Make it all!
all : $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

# Host executable target.
$(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET) : Makefile $(SRCS) $(INCS) $(TARGET_DIR)
        $(ECHO)$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC $(foreach D,$(INC_DIRS),-I$D) \
                        $(AOCL_COMPILE_CONFIG) $(SRCS) $(AOCL_LINK_CONFIG) \
                        $(foreach D,$(LIB_DIRS),-L$D) \
                        $(foreach L,$(LIBS),-l$L) \
                        -o $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(TARGET_DIR) :
        $(ECHO)mkdir $(TARGET_DIR)

# Standard make targets
clean :
        $(ECHO)rm -f $(TARGET_DIR)/$(TARGET)

.PHONY : all clean
```

Comment: What is your Makefile doing when you call `make`?

Comment: @Martin do you want me to post it ?

Comment: Yes. Hard to tell you how to fix it otherwise.

Comment: @Martin I just post the Makefile. Plz check

Comment: Is there a `main` function in any of the files described by ` $(wildcard host/src/*.cpp ../common/src/AOCLUtils/*.cpp)`?

Comment: yes there is a `main.cpp` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236810/discussion-between-user16767585-and-martin).